# Failed to use the interval image capture mode in DJI SDK

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, dji-sdk

This is the code I'm using but it only takes a single photo

```
private fun captureAction() {
        val camera: Camera = getCameraInstance() ?: return

        val photoMode = ShootPhotoMode.INTERVAL

        camera.setShootPhotoMode(photoMode) { djiError ->
            if (djiError == null) {
                lifecycleScope.launch {
                    camera.startShootPhoto { djiErrorSecond ->
                        if (djiErrorSecond == null) {
                            showToast("take photo: success")

                        } else {
                            showToast("Take Photo Failure: ${djiError?.description}")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to take multiple pictures every 3s?

Answer (score 0):

Have you called setPhotoTimeIntervalSettings()? I think you must.

Depending of what drone your using, you can't have to short interval.

Comment: Thank you so much it works!

I also found a simpler method by using DJI widgets